# Quartz connection already closed (1.5.2)

Tags: quartz-scheduler

We are getting this exception after a job fired successfully (quartz 1.5.2):

```
M: 2014-01-08 07:31:14,737 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-9] ERROR org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger  - An error occured while marking executed job complete. job= 'DEFAULT.MIL002_APPLINK_HTTP_SMS_20140108070013' 

org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't close jdbc connection. Already closed. [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: Already closed.] 

    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.closeConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:2299) 

    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.triggeredJobComplete(JobStoreTX.java:1337) 

    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyJobStoreJobComplete(QuartzScheduler.java:1490) 

    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:270) 

    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520) 

* Nested Exception (Underlying Cause) --------------- 

java.sql.SQLException: Already closed. 

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection.close(PoolableConnection.java:77) 

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.close(PoolingDataSource.java:180) 

    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.closeConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:2297) 

    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.triggeredJobComplete(JobStoreTX.java:1337) 

    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyJobStoreJobComplete(QuartzScheduler.java:1490) 

    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:270) 

    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
```

We use the org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate with a SimpleThreadPool.
This class handles the DB: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error when you forcefully close connection from database server. It could be a batch job or scheduled job that runs and blindly closes database connections that were established by SpagoBi.